# Edge data not fully loaded into Neptune (via Python and Gremlin)

Tags: import, filesize, amazon-neptune, upload-max-filesize

I've uploaded my gremlin-csv formatted data to S3 and eventually figured out how to  run the loader gremlin script via Python Jupyter from the terrible AWS documentation, but while the Node data is fully loaded into the graph, the Edge data is not, but there is no error.

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()
url = 'wss://<<cluster>>.<<region>>.neptune.amazonaws.com:<<port>>/gremlin'
remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection(url,'g')
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(url,'g'))
remoteConn.close()
```

That creates an empty graph object, so now I load my data into it using:

```
import requests
import json

url="https://<<cluster>>.<<region>>.neptune.amazonaws.com:<<port>>/loader"
data = {
    "source" : "s3://neptune-data/neptuneEdgeData.csv",
    "format" : "csv",
    "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::<<###>>:role/NeptuneLoadFromS3",
    "region" : "<<region>>",
    "failOnError" : "FALSE",
    "parallelism" : "MEDIUM"
}
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

And this works fine for the Node data, but the EdgeData file doesn't get completely loaded.  One reason may be that the EdgeData file is 455 Mb.  There is a vague and uninformative note on the AWS Neptune limits page:

> The total size of Gremlin and SPARQL HTTP requests must be less than 150 MB. If a request exceeds this size, Neptune returns HTTP 400: BadRequestException.

I didn't get a `BadRequestException` (even when I set `failOnError` to `TRUE`) but it may be only loading ~1/3 of the data because of a size/time limit.

Does anybody actually know why this might be happening and how to get the full edge data loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The 150MB limit that you see in docs is referring to query payload limit. In your case, your query/request is a bulk load request, so the limit does not apply there. There is no limit on the data you have stored in S3. There are few ways to go ahead with this, but it does look like the most useful way would be through a support case, since that would let the engineers take a look at your specific cluster and see whats going on.

What does the `loader status` API tell you for your loadId? Does it say that the load failed with error or does it say it completed? If its the latter, you would see the number of records it was able to insert as part of the load. If it was the former, then there are arguments to the load command that you can use to see more details (errors, failing lines in the file etc) as called out in [1].

My guess is that the edge file has some issues and hence the loader could not parse it properly.

Appreciate you being vocal about the documentation not being too helpful, so would be great if you could share the specific pain points (what was misleading, what was missing etc) and I'll make sure someone addresses them from our end. We're very receptive to feedback from the community.

[1] Loader status API - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-status.html#load-api-reference-status-parameters

Comment: No error messages came out of AWS no matter how/where I looked. It turned out to be a data type problem.  The Pandas dataframe where the data came from silently converted some (but not all) integer columns into floats.  After trying each column separately I found the ones it could and could not load, then setting all the d-types manually allowed me to load the data into Neptune despite the lack of informative messages from AWS.